# signal SIGABRT on return 0

Tags: c, pointers, sigabrt

Everything seems to run fine except when my program attempts to return 0 which is when I get the error:

```
Thread_1: signal SIGABRT
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I think it may be how I'm using my pointers (passing an array of doubles by reference). I believe it has to do with when my memory is freed, I'm a bit new so it's hard to figure this out. Thanks!

EDIT: readGrades() is reading 4 integers from a text file input.txt and adding them to the array that was passed in

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/*
 * readGrades()
 * INPUT:  double array of grades (double grades[])
 * OUTPUT: number of grades read (int numOfGradesRead)
 */
int readGrades(double (*grades)[]) {

int numOfGradesRead = 0,
    count = 0,
    numRead;

char buf[1000];
FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");

if (file == NULL) {
    perror("Can't open file");
} else {
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file)) {

        // Convert buf to integer
        numRead = atoi(buf);

        // Add number read to grades[]
        if (numRead != -999) {
            (*grades)[count] = numRead;
            numOfGradesRead++;
            count++;
        }
    }
}

fclose(file);

return numOfGradesRead;
}

void frequency(double grades[], int numOfGrades) {

}

int main() {

double grades[100];
int i;

// Initialize grades values to 0
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(grades)/sizeof(int); i++) {
    grades[i] = 0;
}

int numOfGradesRead = readGrades(&grades);

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%f", grades[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A major error is the line:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(grades)/sizeof(int); i++) {
```

As a result of that error, you are setting the value of elements of `grades` using out of bound indices, which leads to undefined behavior.

It should be

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(grades)/sizeof(double); i++) {
                                   // ^^^^^^^ Needs to be double not int
```

You can use the convention

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(grades)/sizeof(grades[0]); i++) {
```

to make your code more robust.

Also, instead of using the hard coded number `4` in the `for` loop to print the grades, you probably want to use `numOfGradesRead`. In addition, print a space or a newline between the grades to make the output easier to read.

```
for (i = 0; i < numOfGradesRead; i++) {
    printf("%f\n", grades[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hm looks like this also fixed the problem as well! Thanks a lot, I didn't catch that mistake. Thank you for the other pointers as well, really helpful.